# check and compare the count from two tables without relation

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, sum

I have below tables

Table1: "Demo"
Columns: SSN, sales, Create_DT,Update_Dt

Table2: "Agent"
Columns: SSN,sales, Agent_Name, Create_Dt, Update_DT

Scenario 1 and desired result set:
I want output as 0 if the count of SSN in Demo table is matched with the count of SSN in Agent table
if the count is not matched then I want result as 1

Scenario 2 and desired result set:
I want output as 0 if the sum of sales in Demo table is matched with the sum of sales in Agent table
if the sum is not matched then I want result as 1

Please help on this query part

Thanks

Comment: Please specify any queries that you may have tried.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: With STG as (
    Select count(*) as CNT_S  from Demo
),

TGT as
(
Select count(*) as cnt_t from Agent)

Select STG.CNT_S,TGT.cnt_t,case when STG.CNT_S = TGT.cnt_t then 0 else 1 end as Match from 
STG,TGT - it is working

Answer (score 3):

You can write two queries separately to take counts within the result query

```
SELECT (SELECT count(Demo.SSN) as SSN1 from Demo)!=(SELECT count(Agent.SSN) as SSN2 from Agent) AS Result;
```

Basically what the inner queries does is it checked whether the counts are equal or not and outputs 1 if it is true and 0 if it is false. Since you have asked to output 1 if it is false I used `'!='` sign.

You can try the same procedure in scenario 2 also

Answer (score 0):

For scenario 1

```
select (Case when (select count(ssn) from Demo)=(select count(ssn) from Agent) then 0 else 1 end) as desired_result
```

If you want to count unique ssn then:

```
select (Case when (select count(distinct ssn) from Demo)=(select count(distinct ssn) from Agent) then 0 else 1 end) as desired_result
```

For scenario 2:

```
select (Case when (select sum(sales) from Demo)=(select sum(sales) from Agent) then 0 else 1 end) as desired_result
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest one query with both sets of information:

```
select (d.num_ssn <> a.num_ssn) as have_different_ssn_count,
       (d.sales <> a.sales) as have_different_sales
from (select count(distinct ssn) as num_ssn,
             coalesce(sum(sales), 0) as sales
      from demo
     ) d cross join
     (select count(distinct ssn) as num_ssn, 
             coalesce(sum(sales), 0) as sales
      from agent
     ) a;
```

Note:  This returns boolean values -- `true`/`false` rather than `1`/`0`.  If you *really* want `0`/`1`, then use `case`:

```
select (case when d.num_ssn <> a.num_ssn then 1 else 0 end) as have_different_ssn_count,
       (case when d.sales <> a.sales then 1 else 0 end) as have_different_sales
```

It would not surprise me if you were not only interested in the total counts but also that the agent/sales combinations are the same in both tables.  If that is the case, please ask a *new* question with a clear explanation.  Sample data and desired results help.